# TempData not working in iPhone's Safari browser

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, browser, safari, tempdata

I am using TempData for passing data between actions and it works totally perfect when I run my application on different devices. But when I access it on iPhone's **Safari** browser my TempData is NULL in my `Work` action. If anyone knows whats the problem and how can I solve it?

**Code** Looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[HandleApplicationError(ActionName = "Error", ControllerName = "Affiliates")]
public virtual ActionResult Qualify(QualifyViewModel qualify)
{
    QualificationViewModel qualifyVM = qualify.QualificationViewModel;
    TempData["QualifyViewModel"] = qualify;

    return RedirectToAction(Work, Home);
}

[HandleApplicationError(ActionName = "Error", ControllerName = "Home")]
public virtual ActionResult Work()
{
    QualifyViewModel qualifyVM = TempData["QualifyViewModel"] as QualifyViewModel;

    return Qualify(qualifyVM);
}
```

Comment: TempData is a totally server-side concept, so it's hard to see how the browser could affect it. Are you sure you reproduced exactly the same scenario in your tests?

Comment: @ADyson yes excatly same

Comment: I am having the same problem. TempData does not work on iPhones for Safari and Chrome. 10.26.2022